# create plot of a Chi-Distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution

i try to plot the probability density function of a chi-Distribution with say 20 degrees of freedom. (NOT a CHI-Square distribution!!)
As i found out so far there is the package Runuran in R providing this distribution.
But i cannot get this work.
Anybody familiar with the syntax of this?

My first try looked like this

```
library("Runuran")
zwanzig<-udchi(df=20)
f_zwanzig<-ud(zwanzig,0:10)
curve(from=0, to=10, f_zwanzig)
plot((0:10),f_zwanzig(0:10))
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `f_zwanzig` is not defined as a function, whereas it should be.

```
f_zwanzig <- function(x) ud(zwanzig, x)
curve(from=0, to=10, f_zwanzig)
```

[image]